Flushright an image under a title but aligned beside a name/affiliation
I am creating a poster for a conference presentation and would like to do the following, so that the image is below the title but aligned with my name/affiliation but I get a lot of whitespace above the image:
\begin{figure}[H]

\flushright
\includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{logo}

\end{figure}

I'm thinking I need to use a minipage environment to encapsulate the title, author information, and image together, but I don't currently have it implemented:
\documentclass[final,portrait]{beamer}
\usepackage[orientation=portrait,size=custom,width=90,height=120,scale=1.4]{beamerposter}

% Load additional packages as needed
%\usepackage{graphicx} % For including images
\usepackage{booktabs} % For nicer tables
%\usepackage{multicol} % For multi-column layout

% Define the column separation and margins
\setlength{\columnsep}{2cm}
\setlength{\columnseprule}{0mm}

% Define colors
\definecolor{blue}{RGB}{0, 0, 255}

% Customize the beamer color theme
\setbeamercolor{title}{fg=white, bg=blue}
\setbeamercolor{block title}{fg=white, bg=blue}
\setbeamercolor{block body}{fg=black, bg=white}
\setbeamercolor{author in head/foot}{fg=black, bg=blue}
\setbeamercolor{institute in head/foot}{fg=black, bg=blue}

% Custom block title formatting
\newcommand{\blocktitle}[1]{\vphantom{A}\smash{#1}}

\setbeamerfont{block title}{series=\bfseries}

% Document begins
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[t]
    % Title and author information
    \begin{center}
        \usebeamercolor[fg]{title in head/foot}\textbf{\Huge Here Is My Concise Title For My Conference Presentation} \\[0.5cm]
        \usebeamercolor[fg]{author in head/foot}\Huge Here Is My Name \\[0.2cm]
        \usebeamercolor[fg]{institute in head/foot}\large Here Is My Affiliation 
    \end{center}
    
     \begin{figure}[H]
            \flushright
            \includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{logo}
        \end{figure}

    
    \vspace{1cm} % Adjust the spacing as needed
    
    \begin{columns}[t]

        % First column
        \begin{column}{0.3\textwidth}
            \begin{block}{\blocktitle{Introduction}}
                Your introduction text goes here.
            \end{block}

            \begin{block}{\blocktitle{Methods}}
                Your methods text goes here.
            \end{block}
        \end{column}

        % Second column
        \begin{column}{0.3\textwidth}
            \begin{block}{\blocktitle{Results}}
                Your results text goes here.
            \end{block}

            \begin{block}{\blocktitle{Discussion}}
                Your discussion text goes here.
            \end{block}
        \end{column}

        % Third column
        \begin{column}{0.3\textwidth}
            \begin{block}{\blocktitle{Conclusion}}
                Your conclusion text goes here.
            \end{block}

            \begin{block}{\blocktitle{References}}
                Your references go here.
            \end{block}
            \begin{block}{\blocktitle{Acknowledgements}}
                Your acknowledgements go here.
            \end{block}
        \end{column}

    \end{columns}
\end{frame}

\end{document}

Is this the best way?


Beamer does not have a floating mechanism. There is no real advantage to wrap an image into a figure environment if it does not have a caption.
To position your name etc. beside the image, you could use columns. They have the advantage, that you can nicely align them with the top of the image:
\documentclass[final,portrait]{beamer}
\usepackage[orientation=portrait,size=custom,width=90,height=120,scale=1.4]{beamerposter}

% Load additional packages as needed
%\usepackage{graphicx} % For including images
\usepackage{booktabs} % For nicer tables
%\usepackage{multicol} % For multi-column layout

% Define the column separation and margins
\setlength{\columnsep}{2cm}
\setlength{\columnseprule}{0mm}

% Define colors
\definecolor{blue}{RGB}{0, 0, 255}

% Customize the beamer color theme
\setbeamercolor{title}{fg=white, bg=blue}
\setbeamercolor{block title}{fg=white, bg=blue}
\setbeamercolor{block body}{fg=black, bg=white}
\setbeamercolor{author in head/foot}{fg=black, bg=blue}
\setbeamercolor{institute in head/foot}{fg=black, bg=blue}

% Custom block title formatting
\newcommand{\blocktitle}[1]{\vphantom{A}\smash{#1}}

\setbeamerfont{block title}{series=\bfseries}

\usepackage{tabularx}

% Document begins
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[t]

\usebeamercolor[fg]{title in head/foot}\textbf{\Huge Here Is My Concise Title For My Conference Presentation}
\begin{columns}[onlytextwidth,T]
\begin{column}{.2\textwidth}
\end{column}
\begin{column}{.6\textwidth}
\centering
\usebeamercolor[fg]{author in head/foot}\Huge Here Is My Name \\[0.2cm]
\usebeamercolor[fg]{institute in head/foot}\large Here Is My Affiliation 
\end{column}
\begin{column}{.2\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-duck}
\end{column}
\end{columns}

\vskip1cm
    
    \begin{columns}[t]

        % First column
        \begin{column}{0.3\textwidth}
            \begin{block}{\blocktitle{Introduction}}
                Your introduction text goes here.
            \end{block}

            \begin{block}{\blocktitle{Methods}}
                Your methods text goes here.
            \end{block}
        \end{column}

        % Second column
        \begin{column}{0.3\textwidth}
            \begin{block}{\blocktitle{Results}}
                Your results text goes here.
            \end{block}

            \begin{block}{\blocktitle{Discussion}}
                Your discussion text goes here.
            \end{block}
        \end{column}

        % Third column
        \begin{column}{0.3\textwidth}
            \begin{block}{\blocktitle{Conclusion}}
                Your conclusion text goes here.
            \end{block}

            \begin{block}{\blocktitle{References}}
                Your references go here.
            \end{block}
            \begin{block}{\blocktitle{Acknowledgements}}
                Your acknowledgements go here.
            \end{block}
        \end{column}

    \end{columns}
\end{frame}

\end{document}


Thanks. How would your solution differ I wanted to align the image within the third column to match the alignment of the name/afiliation in the second column. Currently, there seems to be a lot of whitespace that is a bit of an eyesore. Perhaps this should be a new question?

@compbiostats Please ask a new question including a sketch which shows which alignment you are looking for
